# Subversion: how to take incremental backups?

Tags: svn, backup, windows-server-2008, visualsvn-server

I installed VisualSVN Server on Windows Server 2008. Now I would like to create a repository backup plan. My intention is to create full hotcopy bakcup (using `svnadmin hotcopy` and then incremental backups. How to do a incremental backup using `svnadmin.exe`? Or should I take only `svnadmin dump` backups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command for that:

```
svnadmin dump --incremental repository >result.inc
```

What size are you repositories? It's really worth the effort to create incremental backups instead full backups?
BTW: an svnadmin dump --help had helped.

Comment: Thanks, our repository is not large. But I was thinking that is hotcopy preferred over taking dump backups?

Comment: personally i prefere dump files over hotcopy...but depending on the size you come to point where you need to do it via htocopy instead...Many people using hotcopy...May be might a btter idea to make a stand-by-server which is update via svnsync (by every commit)...so the stand-by-server can be backup'ed independent of the production server. In case of an emergency you can use the stand-by-server to continue working.